# SSAS Time Series Algorithm key time increment

Tags: sql, ssas

I am using SSAS Time series algorithm with monthly sales data. I have a separate column as monthyear(201601,201602,201603..etc) which have month and year as combination.

In my model even though the prediction results are correct, key time increment is wrong.It goes as 201612,201613,201614..etc. But originally it should be 201701 after 201612.

here I attached the screen shot also. If anyone know how to solve this, help me plz.[image]

Answer (score 0):

when prepare the SQL view to create the model MonthYear column should be created using date functions given by sql.

EX: CAST(DATENAME(yy, sales.SalesRecord.DateAsOf)  + '00' + DATEPART(mm, sales.SalesRecord.DateAsOf) AS int) AS MonthYear